# Jekyll Wiping My Directory

Tags: jekyll

I followed the instructions for Jekyll Quickstart. Whenever I make changes in my site's directory, the changes get wiped somehow. For example, I modified some of the code in `index.html`, only to have it return to Jekyll's default. I also created a subdirectory in `_site` called 'otherservices' with an `index.html`. That gets wiped as well. Any idea why this may be happening? I can't really use Jekyll if it keeps wiping.

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll is a static website generator, each time it generates a website it place files in the `_site` folder.

Any changes you make inside the above folder are lost because it is recreated when executing `jekyll build` or `jekyll serve` .

Changes should be made to the rest of the files or folders so they will be processed and locate the resulting files inside `_site`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write manually into `_site` directory, that is Jekyll's output.

If you need an `otherservices` directory in the output, place it one level above, like this:

```
_site/
otherservices/
    index.html
index.md
```

Jekyll will copy every file and directory into `_site`, which is not excluded in the configuration and doesn't start with `_` prefix. Files that have [front-matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) will be processed in addition to copying. So in result Jekyll will generate this structure:

```
_site/
    otherservices/ (copies it)
        index.html
    index.html     (generates it from index.md)
otherservices/
    index.html
index.md
```

It is worth reading the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) on how to create custom pages.