# I can't edit Jekyll index.html

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to change /_site/about in index.html. When I edit the index.html and start jekyll, index.html  back to it's original content.

Sorry for my english.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jekyll Wiping My Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660789/jekyll-wiping-my-directory)

Answer (score 2):

You don't edit files inside the `/_site` directory. When jekyll builds the site, it overwrites any and all files in that directory.

Edit the `index.html` file in the `/about/` directory **outside** of the `/_site/` folder.

Run the command `jekyll build` to apply these changes to the generated site.

Or use `jekyll serve` to automatically host the content locally and update the content when a change is made.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to edit Index.html file as it is generated from the markdown file your provided which as we all know is called index.md, whenever you change that file and run `jekyll build` it re-generates the index.html file hence if you edit once you would have to do the same again when you change index.md file.

So directly write html / markdown in index.md file in your jekyll directory.

Best,

Daksh